# Enumerate environment variables in C++ (cross-platform)

Tags: c++, cross-platform, environment-variables

Just a quick question and I hope that hasn't been asked before. I want to know a way to list all the assigned environment variables for a process. I need it to be cross-platform across Windows and UNIX-like operating systems.

I know `getenv()` but that only retrieves a variable's value. I need to generate a list of them.

Thank you for help!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c

Comment: Not quite a dup, this asks for a POSIX method.  The answer to the other question is non-standard, though a non-accepted answer is POSIX.

Comment: "across **Windows** and UNIX-like operating systems."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're just looking for the 3rd argument to main, a char** of process environment variables.

Here ya go: [Main function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function_%28programming%29)

The prototype for that form is `int main(int argc,char** argv,char** env)`

Comment: @Electro OP specifically mentions Windows and UNIXes, and according to the wiki page it works on both of them.

Comment: My apologies if that doesn't suit the bill. Perhaps it's my limited experience, but between various unixen, os-x and windows, I haven't encountered a platform where it didn't work.

Comment: It does **not** work on Windows if you need non-ANSI characters.  For that, you have to use `int wmain(int, wchar_t**, wchar_t**)`.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for the global variable [`environ`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html).

Comment: From all indicators I've seen, this is POSIX.

Comment: @Tibor Windows has it too, but you're not supposed to declare it the way you do for POSIX. On Windows it's declared for you in cstdlib.