# Undefined reference to 'environ'?

Tags: c

I am trying to use the 'environ' variable, but it keeps giving me an error. It seems to be a makefile/build error and I can't seem to fix it. I have searched fo answers, but still I am lost.

Here is my c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "cmd.h" 

int cmdExec() {
...
extern char **environ;
...


printf("Enter a command\n");
//gets (input);
scanf("%s%*[^\n]", input);

if (...) {
    ...
}
else if (strcmp(input, "environ") == 0) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; environ[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", environ[i]);
    }
    exit(0);
else
    ...

return 0;
}
```

and here is the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c
CFLAGS-y = -std=c99

all: cmd

cmd.o: cmd.c cmd.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFLAGS-y) cmd.c

cmd.exe: cmd.o
    $(CC) -o cmd.exe cmd.o  

clean:
    rm -rf *.o cmd.exe a.out
```

This is the output:

```
make all 
gcc -c -std=c99 cmd.c
gcc   cmd.o   -o cmd
cmd.o:cmd.c:(.text+0x105): undefined reference to `environ'
cmd.o:cmd.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `environ'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cmd] Error 1
```

From what I've searched this deals with linking libraries, but I don't know how to apply that to my specific situation. If someone could give me a hand I'd appreciate it.

Comment: What system are you on? Does a simple "hello, world" program compile, link, and execute correctly?

Comment: I'm on Windows 7 and yeah everything worked fine until I tried to use 'environ'.

Comment: What gcc are you using? Cygwin? MinGW? Something else?

Comment: `environ` is a POSIX standard variable. Even when using an environment such as MinGW it might not exist on Windows. Also, the [standard specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) that "The `environ` array should not be accessed directly by the application."

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: That's find for programs that know which environment variables they need to use (and `getenv()` is standard C, so it should work find on Windows) -- but then how would you implement something like the `printenv` command?

Comment: @KeithThompson I'm using MinGW. At Joachim, that makes sense. I check what I can do about it.

Comment: @KeithThompson Well the specification says "_should_ not", not "_must_ not" access the variable, so there is some leeway.

Comment: Does it work in Windows if you declare `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` ?

Comment: @teppic: I don't know, but I doubt it. Most likely the compiler won't complain (unless you crank the warning levels way up), but `envp` will be garbage. But it looks like there is a Windows-specific solution, which I'll post as an answer in a moment.

Comment: @teppic Currently I'm not using the command line (since I'm still learning how to do this), but my instructions state that the preferred way is using 2 arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all(if any) compilers on Windows provides access to environment variables through a global symbol named `environ`.

You can use e.g. [getenv](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tehxacec%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)() to access environment variables.

The win32 API provides [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)() to access all the variables.

Some platforms allow you to access the environment through an additional argument to main(), you'd declare your main function as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *environ[])
```

Comment: Cygwin provides a POSIX-like environment on top of Windows. The OP probably isn't using Cygwin.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think I'm coming to the conclusion of using getenv, putenv, and setenv (as listed in my instructions) instead of environ. Because my instructions don't explicitly state it, would those methods be sufficient replacements for environ?

Comment: After doing some reading and understanding, I think that the method suggested in this answer will work for me personally, but for the person grading I think my original code will work for them since they will be using a linux system. At least I hope.

Comment: If you only need access to specific environment variables, don't bother with `environ` or `GetEnvironmentStrings`, just use the standard `getenv()` function. If you need to update environment variables, `setenv()` is more flexible than `putenv()`.

Comment: @keithThompson I understand that much about it, but I'm going to need to list all of the environment variables. system("set") does the job on my system so I just commented out the original code for the grader to test later.

Answer (score 2):

The `environ` global variable is defined by POSIX, and is not supported by Windows (unless you're using Cygwin, which is a POSIX-like layer implemented on top of Windows).

As far as I know, the non-standard definition

```
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) { /* ... */ }
```

is also not supported on Windows.

But a quick Google search turned up [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085346/827263), which points to the documentation for the Windows-specific [GetEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683187%28VS.85%29.aspx) function:

```
LPTCH WINAPI GetEnvironmentStrings(void);
```

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a pointer to the
>   environment block of the current process.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`.

The result points to a long string with the environment variables separated by `'\0'` null characters, with the environment terminated by two consecutive null characters.

`LPTCH` is Microsoft's typedef for a pointer to either `unsigned char` or a 16-bit `wchar_t`. See the referenced documentation for more information.