# the function getenv() always returning null

Tags: c

my program

```
int main(void){
printf("Log file location : %s\n", getenv("LOG_FILE"));
return 0;
}
```

is always printing null.

but i already set the env in

/etc/nagios/.profile file where my user is "nagios" by **export LOG_FILE=/root/log**

and i am also able to see the same when i am executing the **"env"** command in terminal.

Comment: maybe you forget to write  `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: what does `env` report from the command line before you invoke the program? Does it contain the variable `LOG_FILE`? You've probably simply not sourced the `.profile` script before running the program which means that the variable is not set.

Comment: Check your all your environment variables if LOG_FILE is set or not ... [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c)

Comment: Please note that your question is not actually about getenv(), it is about where you need to set environment variables in the Nagios monitoring systems so that Nagios plugins can see them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function `getenv` shows a very interesting results if you forget to write `#include <stdlib.h>` into header of your file.

For example, code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
  printf("Log file location : %s\n", getenv("LOG_FILE"));
  return 0;
}
```

works pretty well:

```
LOG_FILE="log" ./a.out 
Log file location : log
```

But when I comment out second line, I get:

```
LOG_FILE="log" ./a.out 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: no i already included the header file, actually i post a part of the code.

Comment: If `env` shows right value of "LOG_FILE", but this tool don't, I think, problem may be in some other place of your code.