# why System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME") returns null?

Tags: java, environment-variables

I define a system variable `CATALINA_HOME` which refers to tomcat installation directory in my OS system(windows 7 ultimate 64 bit), now I want to get it by java, my code is below:

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME"));
```

it returns null, I am pretty sure this variable exists in my system, I type `set catalina_home` in cmd console, it shows exactly the value assigned to it.

So why can't I get it, or is there other way to get system env variable?

*PS*: the below are all variables retrieved by `System.getenv()`.

```
    Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String key : env.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(key + ":" + env.get(key));
    }

    System.out.println(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME"));
```

output:

```
USERPROFILE:C:\Users\chorusheng
ProgramData:C:\ProgramData
PATHEXT:.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
JAVA_HOME:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20
ProgramFiles(x86):C:\Program Files (x86)
TEMP:C:\Users\CHORUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp
SystemDrive:C:
ProgramFiles:C:\Program Files
Path:C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;d:\Program Files (x86)\KOUTON\CTBS Standard Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\NetSarang;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec BioExcess\;C:\Program Files (x86)\EgisTec BioExcess\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;d:\Program Files (x86)\Tencent\QQPCMgr\6.6.2150.401;D:\Program Files (x86)\TortoiseSVN\bin;d:\Program Files (x86)\DigiWin OpenVPN\bin;d:\Program Files (x86)\Tencent\QQPCMgr\6.6.2150.401;F:\chega\eclipsej2ee3.7;
HOMEDRIVE:C:
DYNA_HOME:E:\plm
PROCESSOR_REVISION:2502
USERDOMAIN:chorus
ALLUSERSPROFILE:C:\ProgramData
ProgramW6432:C:\Program Files
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER:Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel
SESSIONNAME:Console
TMP:C:\Users\CHORUS~1\AppData\Local\Temp
CommonProgramFiles:C:\Program Files\Common Files
CLASSPATH:.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\lib\dt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\lib\tools.jar;
LOGONSERVER:\\CHORUS
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE:AMD64
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK:NO
OS:Windows_NT
HOMEPATH:\Users\chorusheng
PROCESSOR_LEVEL:6
CommonProgramW6432:C:\Program Files\Common Files
1830B7BD-F7A3-4c4d-989B-C004DE465EDE:f44:431b280
LOCALAPPDATA:C:\Users\chorusheng\AppData\Local
COMPUTERNAME:CHORUS
windir:C:\Windows
SystemRoot:C:\Windows
asl.log:Destination=file
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS:4
USERNAME:chorusheng
PUBLIC:C:\Users\Public
PSModulePath:C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
CommonProgramFiles(x86):C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
ComSpec:C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
APPDATA:C:\Users\chorusheng\AppData\Roaming
null
```

as we can see, the last line is null which is the value of CATALINA_HOME variable.

*PS*: my tomcat is not an installation edition.

Comment: can you return other enviroment variables? or is just CATALINA_HOME not working? from where are you running your code (eclipse)?

Comment: @PhilippSander, System.getenv() returns more `varialbes` than I can see in OS env variables list(in System property dialog), all variables except CATALINA_HOME can be retrieved by `getenv()`, and CATALINA_HOME is the ONLY ONE not working.

Comment: Is it set as a system variable, or as a user variable?

Comment: Have you set it through `My Computer > Advanced > Environment Variables` or just `set CATALINA_HOME` in a commandline window? Because the second is local for that window.

Comment: @Theodoros, I use the first way to set `CATALINA_HOME` variable.

Comment: See whether other processes can see that environment variable. For example, if you have a C/C++ compiler handy, use this to check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possible reasons:

1. You've used `set CATALINA_HOME` in a command prompt. That makes this variable local to this window. It should be visible to processes started from this command prompt but nowhere else. Use `My Computer > Advanced > Environment Variables` to make a variable visible to all new processes.
2. The process which tries to read the variable is already running. Restart it.

   Note: That could be the IDE if you start Tomcat from the debugger or the standalone Tomcat process when you start it from the command line.
3. The start script of Tomcat unsets the variable before it invokes `java.exe`
4. Tomcat unsets the variable in it's Java code.

Comment: reason 1: I set `CATALINA_HOME` in `My Compuer>Advanced>Envronments VAriables`, not commandline way.  reason 2 and reason3: I now do not start tomcat, just in my unit test class to get `CATAALINA_HOME` variable.

Comment: My unit test class likes this:`public class TestEnv {

 @Test
 public void test() {
  System.out.println(System.getenv("CATALINA_HOME"));
 }
}`  start by clicking `Run as > junit test` in context menu. And I am home now, I just test on my PC(windows xp), this code works well for me, if I delete CATALINA_HOME variable, it also outputs non-null value, and if I add a new env variable,i.e. CATALINA_BASE, it returns null, so it seems like that it's a cache problem, may I restart my PC?

Comment: I found a solution: shutdown eclipse and start(not `Restart` in `File` menu), the code will work as expected. This is very strange to me, it seems that eclipse caches system env variables as opening. Do you have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, see reason #2 in my answer: Setting variable doesn't change them for already running processes.

Comment: Thanks for this.  This is also true in Eclipse.  I assumed wrongly that running a program in Eclipse would be in a new process.  I had to restart Eclipse to get a new variable show up.

Comment: A process always inherits from it's parent and not from the OS. So as long as you don't restart Eclipse, all its children will see the old values.

Comment: Closed and again open eclipse resolve mine issue. Restart eclipse didn't work.

Comment: @bugCracker: Correct. Restarting Eclipse with the menu item doesn't work because Eclipse has a hidden parent process which launches Java. Since the Java process inherits the variables from the hidden parent, it will only see new env variables when the hidden parent process is restarted.

Comment: @hiway The same goes for the IntelliJ. Restart didn't work, I had to manually shut down the IDE and then turn it on again.

Answer (score 6):

If method `system.getenv("some name")` return `null` probably you define this variable in your environment after lunching your Eclipse IDE. Just restart your Eclipse and then run your project again.

Comment: The same happened to me with IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.3.3. I had to close all IntelliJ windows and reopen my app, only then I got a value in `String catalinaHome = System.getEnv("CATALINA_HOME");`

Comment: It happend with me as well. IDE takes env variable at the time it was opened after that whatever you do in terminal will not effect the IDE. have to restart it inorder to get it reflected in IDE. With me i had to restart the laptop to get it working