# Reading system environment variable in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, security, gradle, environment-variables

I'm bit curious for learning how can we load private credentials from system environment variables (Windows/Mac/Linux) in Android `build.gradle` or any other gradle configuration file.
There might be ways or approaches through which we can achieve this but really looking for directions.

> **Couple of things I already explored but didn't work for me are:**
>
> Note: I tried on Windows Environment and getting `null`.
>
> [In Gradle, is there a better way to get Environment Variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854176/in-gradle-is-there-a-better-way-to-get-environment-variables)
>
> https://javabydeveloper.com/gradle-system-properties-via-command-line-step-by-step-example/
>
> [How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21406265/how-to-give-system-property-to-my-test-via-gradle-and-d)
>
> https://dzone.com/articles/specifying-gradle-build
>
> https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-should-i-be-handling-passing-system-properties-from-gradle-to-my-tests/7171/3

Comment: What does "didn't work for me" mean? What were your symptoms? Also, where and how are you using Gradle: command line? CI server? Android Studio? Some other IDE?

Comment: If you need data for signing keys, I would create gradle.properties file and store it in:
~/.gradle/gradle.properties. (on Mac)

Comment: I'm using trying to access in `build.gradle` file in Android Studio to fetch system environment variables and I get `NULL` via every approach mentioned in links.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16414092/6645076

Answer (score 5):

You can access a variable called `MY_VAR` using `System.getenv('MY_VAR')` in a Gradle script. If the variable doesn’t exist, then `null` is returned. This should work equally well on all platforms.

For example, with the `build.gradle` script

```groovy
def myVar = System.getenv('MY_VAR')
println(myVar)
```

the Gradle command `MY_VAR='it works!' ./gradlew projects` outputs the following (and some more) on the console (tested in a Linux shell with Gradle 7.2):

```
> Configure project :
it works!
```

Comment: Quite strange, I get `Null` when I try to access it just like you are doing.

Comment: I assume you got `null` (all lower-case)? Did you run the _exact same_ command in a Linux bash shell? Are you sure the environment variable is set for the process from which you try to access it?

Comment: I am using Windows 10, and once I set the System Environment variable I do not get anything in `gradle` when I run it. Would you try on your Windows please?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have a Windows system to test this with. However, the issue sounds like the environment variable is simply not correctly made available to the `gradle` process. Do you see the variable when you print the entire set of environment variables in your `build.gradle` (e.g., with `println(System.getenv())`)?