# Check if env is empty

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, development-environment

I'm writing a program for my school.

I need to use term env but if correctors start my program with env -i, my program segfault.

How to avoid an empty env in C when starting my program ?

Thanks

Comment: By checking that the pointer returned by [`getenv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) is not `NULL`? And don't make code for some specific environment unless you also have a default fallback.

Comment: Use of getenv is forbidden by the exercise rules..

Comment: Simillar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c) question. Note that looping through them all, the string (`thisEnv` in that example), will contain the **variable=somthing**, as in `TERM=vt100`, so you will have to tokenize it too.

Answer (score 0):

In normal case::

```
#include <stdio.h>

main (int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
    // Do Something.
    char *envHomepath;
    envHomepath = getenv("HOME");
    if (envHomepath == NULL)
        printf("HOME env is NULL\n");
    else
        printf("HOME env is %s\n", envHomepath); 

    return 0;
}
```

then 
It'll output to console

HOME env is /user/xxxxx.xxx  <-- it's your username.

Answer (score 0):

You have several ways to access the environment:

1. as a third parameter to main (`int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp);`)
2. through the **environ** global variable (`char **environ;`)
3. through the **getenv(3)** library function.  This only makes a search through the environment for a string of the form `"VARNAME=value"`.

The environment is always present, as it is normally passed to the process through the `exec(2)` system call from the parent process (in unix and MS-DOS/Windows systems) as a group of nul (\0) terminated strings, followed by a nul (another \0 following the last string) so the end of the environment might be two nul's in sequence (this is how it's passed on msdos, in other unices you can have another way to do this).  A null environment would be to pass an empty array of strings (just a `NULL` pointer to signal the end of the environment).

Despite of this, what `main()` receives (and the `environ` variable also) is an array of `char` pointers to strings (normally prepared through the basic C runtime), followed by a `NULL` pointer to signal de end, so an empty environment would be something like:

```
char **environ = { NULL }; /* at least a NULL pointer to indicate the end of the environment */
```

If you check for this ( `if (environ[0] == NULL)` ), you'll get an indication of an empty environment.  Beware that you have to explicitly call the proper **exec(2)** call to include an empty array of environment strings for this to happen.  This is a very uncommon case and probably you'll get into trouble if you try to call many standard programs with an empty environment.

The same applies to the arg list, in this case, almost all unices follow the convention of putting a NULL at argv[argc] and you can do the same, but beware as you almost always have one string there (the program name) so

```
env
```

is received in main with:

```
int argc = 1;
char **argv = { "env", NULL };
```

and

```
env -i
```

would be received in main as:

```
int argc = 2;
char **argv = { "env", "-i", NULL };
```

Also, it's possible (in unix, not in ms-dos) to pass an empty arg list.  This is very uncommon and architecture dependent (linux uses it to ask a shared executable ---a .so file--- what dependencies it has) So it is very rare to expect an empty argument list.

You can detect it checking `if (argc == 0)`, for example.

I'm talking from memory, but I think the convention of putting `NULL` at the end of the `argv` list is a POSIX convention.  Comments are welcome.