# AMD CodeXL breaks my Qt application development environment

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

Recently I re-installed CodeXL add-on from AMD for MSVC 2013. It broke my development environment for Qt5 apps.

Basically when I run Qt app within MSVC 2013, Visual Studio sets the PATH variable so that add-in path c:\Program Files (x86)\CodeXL\ is before my system PATH variable, which contains c:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013\bin\ on the first place in the list.

Since CodeXL contains Qt5 dlls in it's path, it confuses my application. Symptoms are that e.g. Qt5 windows plug-in is not found correctly.

How can I fix this dll mess, so that CodeXL path is not prepended, but appended after my system PATH?

I got the PATH that my app see like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2085385/1068199

Comment: When does VS corrupt the PATH? Do you see it in Debugging Property Page?

Comment: In Debugging, there is empty "Environment" and in VC++Directories, there are Executable Directories filled with some MSVC variables like VC_ExecutablePath WindowsSDK_ExecutablePath etc.

Comment: Empty? Try to set it to `PATH="$(QTDIR)\bin;$(PATH)`.

Comment: Great, now the path for that particular target has the Qt dir on the first place! But it sometimes still confuses Qt app and only when I rename CodeXL directory in Program Files, it works. So I suppose somehow some Qt settings is still fetched from CodeXL :-/

Comment: What is "sometimes"? What does it depend on?

Comment: "sometimes" was actually always. I uninstalled the extension in order to solve my problem. 

So I suppose it depends if CodeXL directory is in path on arbitrary place.I also tried to set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH globally, but it broke some existing Qt apps in my OS. I tried to set the variable only in MSVC, but that did not work for me, I don't know why.