# php run c++ programming occur segmentation fault

Tags: php, c++, fault

Platform: Raspberry Pi2 Raspbian Stretch
Webserver: Apache and Php

I am trying to "passthru" a C++ program through PHP web page. When I run the same program directly on terminal, it works fine, but when I "passthru" or "exec" it through PHP, I get a segmentation fault.

My program did connect to an external mysql server. I notice, if I break down step by step, the segmentation fault occur after mysql_fetch_query.
I did include  and as mentioned above, it run fine in console or terminal.

What else should I check?

Comment: Have you compared the environment variables? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c
Also, are you running PHP as the same user?