# idiomatic C++14/C++17 approach to enumerating environment variables

Tags: c++, environment-variables, c++14, c++17

Here is the code to enumerate all the environment variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

      char **p = nullptr;

      p = envp;

      while (*p) {
            std::cout << *p << std::endl;
            p++;
      }

return 0;
}
```

i have referred to the earlier post about [printing all environment variables in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c). However, it doesn't answer my query.

How to write the above code in idiomatic C++14/C++17 ? Any pointers ?

update 1 revised code (post Alex suggestion)

NOTE: this will *not* compile as `envp` is not a container.

```
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]) {

      for (auto it = std::begin(envp); it != std::end(envp); ++it) {

            std::cout << *it << std::endl;
      }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(auto it = std::begin(envp), it != std::end(envp); ++it) std::cout << *it << std::endl;`

Comment: Exactly what is wrong with the 1st answer in the question you have linked ?

Comment: @AlexLarionov

```
mismatched types ‘const std::valarray<_Tp>’ and ‘char**’
       for (auto it = std::begin(envp); it != std::end(envp); ++it) {
                                     ^
env_idio.cc:6:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘end(char**&)’
       for (auto it = std::begin(envp); it != std::end(envp); ++it) {
                                                           ^
```

Comment: @RichardCritten none of the answers in that link talk about idiomatic approach to be adopted for C++14/C++17 code.

Comment: `std::end(envp)` will not work, envp is not a standard container.

Comment: Or just use something like https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp

Comment: The (linked) code is clean, easy to read and constrained by interface to `main`.  It is C++14/C++17 code as it compiles with those setting.  Still not sure what you are after.

Comment: @RichardCritten would like to avoid 'naked' pointers ie. char* and char** and instead switch to using a container. Does that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way to enumerate the environment variables than you have in your question or in the linked answers. The reason is that the interface to environment variables is defined in such a way that C code can access them, so you have to do it "the C way" even in C++. C++ does not define its own way to access environment variables.