# Get list of all environment variables in Fortran in portable manner?

Tags: fortran, environment-variables

In our Fortran software, debug parameters can be passed using environment variables with a pattern `PREFIX_KEY`. I want to perform a check, whether the given KEY exists in order to guard against typos.

I know about `GET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE` (Fortran 2003), and this is what the code uses for querying the variables. Is there also a portable manner of enumerating all environment variables, so I can check them for unexpected `PREFIX_KEY` variables?

The software is running in both Linux and Windows environments, and built with different compilers for both platform support and code verification. Portability is thus a big concern.

Comment: As Vladimir says not in pure Fortran, but if you work in a POSIX environment you might look at adapting the C in the second answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085302/printing-all-environment-variables-in-c-c

Comment: @IanBush The software is running across different platforms. I clarified this point in the question.

Comment: True, but note POSIX is an API, not a platform. It should work with different compilers on different Unix like operating systems. But I can't help you  with windows as I don't use it.

Comment: It is extremely likely that you have to choose different approaches at different platforms. There are no platform-independent solutions for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such functionality in the Fortran standard. In Linux you can run `env`, store the output to a file and parse it.

Comment: Windows equivalent would be `set` apparently (in `cmd`). Though both are not safe with regard to variable values containing newlines.